Equivalence closures and coequalizers
It is my impression that coequalizers may be defined on non-congruences. But various sources (MSE - Co-equalizers in Set, "Examples of Co-equalizers" in Smith's Introducing Category Theory) seem to imply that in $\mathsf{Set}$, coequalizers may be implemented solely as natural projections from quotients by equivalence relations, in particular the equivalence closure of the relation induced by $f, g$. What happens if we consider the quotient by the relations per se, without closure? Would the quotient objects be isomorphic?
Let's use the following definition for quotients:

Let $X$ be a set. Associate with each $a \in X$ an $R$-class, $[a]_R = \{x \in X : aRx\}$. Then the quotient of $X$ with respect to $R$ is $X/R = \{[x]_R : x \in X\}$.


You first need to clarify what you mean by "the quotient by the relations per se, without closure". Can you give a precise definition?

Ok, you've added a proposed definition $X/R$, where $R$ is an arbitrary binary relation on $X$. That's great. Now can you clarify how you propose to use this construction as a coequalizer? I.e., given $f,g\colon Y\to X$, what relation $R$ on $X$ are you considering?

Remember that quotients are a way of turning a relation $R$ into equality. But equality is an equivalence relation, so something must happen to make $R$ one as well. In HoTT you can naturally express the quotient of a set by an arbitrary relation as a higher inductive type (see e.g. here), but what you get is really the quotient by the induced congruence because of the built-in $\infty$-groupoid structure on types.

This definition simply does not do anything meaningful unless $R$ is an equivalence relation. Note that you already have to make a non-canonical choice about whether to define $[a]_R$ as $\{ x : aRx \}$ or $\{ x : xRa \}$ because you haven't assumed that $R$ is symmetric; that's a clue that this construction is not a meaningful operation to perform.
Explicitly, let $f, g : Y \to X$ be a coequalizer diagram. This is exactly the same thing as a directed graph with vertex set $X$ and edge set $Y$, if we interpret $f$ as describing the source of a directed edge $y \in Y$ and $g$ as describing the target. The coequalizer is defined as the quotient by the equivalence relation $\overline{R}$ generated by the relation $R \subset X \times X$ generated by $f(y) \sim g(y)$. This relation $R$ is exactly the relation that two vertices are connected by some directed edge, and so its equivalence closure is the relation that two vertices are in the same "weak connected component" (connected by a zigzag of directed edges, or equivalently by a path of undirected edges, where we've forgotten the directions, and zigzags / paths can have length $0$).
If you don't take the equivalence closure then $[x]_R$ just consists of all vertices $x'$ such that there is a directed edge $x \to x'$. In general the relation $R$ can be totally arbitrary, and for example $[x]_R$ need not even contain $x$! In the extreme case we can take $Y = \emptyset$ to be empty in which case all the sets $[x]_R$ are also empty; then your "quotient" is $\{ \emptyset \}$, but the correct coequalizer is $X$.

Wouldn't the quotient be ${\emptyset, \emptyset, \dots}$ with the same cardinality as $X$?

@n1lp0tence: those are all the same set, so the quotient is ${ \emptyset }$. The correct quotient is the quotient by the identity equivalence relation which is ${ { x } : x \in X } \cong X$. In any case this isn't the only thing that can go wrong, e.g. you can consider $X$ a three-element set with directed edges $a \to b \to c$; then your "quotient" is ${ { b }, { c } }$ but the correct quotient is a point.
